# MetaMask: How to sign multiple transactions with only one signature popup

Tags: metamask

I have to send multiple transactions from my front-end, usually for every transaction the user is asked to sign on MetaMask. Is there a way to sign all of them at once in MetaMask, instead of the popup happening for all of the transactions?

Comment: Have you manged to figure this one out? Thanks